# Relationship (foreignkey) CakePhp

Tags: php, cakephp, foreign-keys, cakephp-2.0, foreign-key-relationship

i have a problem creation the relation (foreign Key) between mi models (tables), i followed the cake documentation but doesn't work

the relationship is Marca 1-N Modelos

model Marca.php

```
<?php
class Marca extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Marca';
    public $displayField = 'nombre';
    var $hasMany = array(
        'Modelo' => array(
            'className' => 'Modelo',
            'foreignKey' => 'marca_id'
        )
    );

}

?>
```

model Modelo.php

```
<?php
class Modelo extends AppModel
{
    var $name = 'Modelo';
    var $belongsTo = array(
        'Marca' => array(
            'className' => 'Marca',
            'foreignKey' => 'marca_id'
        )
    );

}

?>
```

ModelosController

```
<?php
class ModelosController extends AppController{
    var $name = 'Modelos';
    var $helpers = array('Html','Form');
    //var $scaffold;

    function index(){
        $modelos = $this->Modelo->find('all',array(
            'fields'=>array(
                'Modelo.nombre',
                'Modelo.valido',
                'Modelo.id',
                'Modelo.marca_id'),
            'order'=>'Modelo.nombre ASC')
        );
        $this->set('modelos',$modelos);
    }

    function add(){
        if (!empty($this->data)){
            $this->Modelo->create();

            if ($this->Modelo->save($this->data)){
                $this->Session->SetFlash('Modelo Nuevo Creado');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
            }else{
                $this->Session->SetFlash('No se ha Agregado el Modelo, intente de Nuevo');
            }
        }
        // $this->loadModel('Marca');
        $marcas = $this->Modelo->Marca->find('list');    <<-----this is 31 line, where is the error
        debug($marcas);
        $this->set(compact('marcas'));
    }

    function edit($id = null){
        if (!$id){
            $this->Session->SetFlash('Modelo Incorrecto');
            $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
        }

        if (empty($this->data)){
            $this->data = $this->Modelo->find('first',array('conditions'=>array('Modelo.id'=> $id)));     
        }else{
            if ($this->Modelo->save($this->data)) {
                $this->Session->SetFlash('El Modelo se ha Guardado');
                $this->redirect(array('action'=>'index'),null,true);
            }else{
                $this->Session->SetFlash('La Modelo No fue Guardado, intente de Nuevo');
            }
        }
    } 
}


?>
```

the error throws is:

Error: Call to a member function find() on a non-object 
File: /var/www/tlfmovil/app/Controller/ModelosController.php
Line: 31

i think the error is because the relation is not set up correctly, please helpe me.

Sorry for my bad english!

Comment: Problem with not using english for naming is that conventions get screwed up because the plurals are handled differently. Try setting `public $useTable = 'marcas';` in your Marca model.

Comment: @nuns - there error doesn't have to do with lack of a table, it's due to not finding the Model because something w/ the associations are not working.

Comment: Check if the `Modelo` model is actually used and CakePHP doesn't generate a 'generic' model; `debug(get_class($this->Modelo));`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your associations seem fine even with `var`, it should not be a database problem either, otherwise Cake would inform you of a missing database table.

You should however stick more to CakePHP conventions to be sure the problem does not come from a typo.
Use the cake bake console or an [online CakePHP baking tool](http://patisserie.keensoftware.com/en/cakes/bake) to generate your Model and Controller files (you can always change the translation to spanish afterwards) to rule out a convention problem in your code.

Comment: I tried your code and it works fine by me. Are you sure your Models filename does not have a typo in it ?

Comment: took 2 days trying to find the solution to that and the validation of the forms and did not know why ... the problem was that the model name beginning with uppercase, I noticed through the link you placed .. when I saw the model beginning with uppercase

Thank you Chris
PD: put the link on favorites xD

Comment: Glad you found the solution and that the online baking tool helped ! :)

Answer (score 0):

Try using `public` instead of `var` when specifying `$belongsTo` and `$hasMany` vars.